# Toggle event fires on second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

There is a module/view definition:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/product.html'], 
function($, _, Backbone, productTemplate) {
    var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "li",
        className: "span3",
        events: {
            "click button.view-details": "viewDetailed"
        },
        viewDetailed: function(e) {
            var _view = this;
            $(e.currentTarget).toggle(
                function() {
                    $(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-eye-open');
                    $(this).find('i').addClass('icon-eye-close');
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-eye-close');
                    $(this).find('i').addClass('icon-eye-open');
                }
            );
        },
        initialize: function() {
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
            this.model.bind('destroy', this.close, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(productTemplate, this.model.toJSON());
            this.$el.append(compiledTemplate);
            return this;
        }
    });
    return ProductView;
});
```

Pressing `button.view-details` for the first time gives no effect (as far as I understand it simply registers `toggle` event). How do I define it the right way?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with that [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) call?

Comment: I was planning to view some detailed information on product not just toggle an image on click. But I can see the image toggled only on my second click.

Comment: Check the documentation I linked to, `toggle` doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need

```
viewDetailed: function(e) {
        var _view = this;
        $(e.currentTarget).toggle(
            function() {
                $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-eye-closed icon-eye-open');
        });
    }
```

Or just bind the function to the button.view-details

```
$('button.view-details').on('click', function() {
    var _view = this;
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-eye-closed icon-eye-open');
});
```

Comment: I think the second one makes the most sense but you'd probably want to bind the click handler through the view's `events` and you don't need the `_view`.